# Weak Operator Convergence Example

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Consider the bounded operators $W_n$ $(n=1,2,3,...)$ on $\ell_2$ defined by:
$$W_n(x_1,x_2,...) = (0,0,...,x_1,x_2,...),$$
with the first $n$ entries being replaced by $0$. This corresponds to a "shift" in the vector $x$. Show that the operator $W_n \to 0$ in the weak operator topology. Please be as explicit as possible in the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I denote the right shift and left shift by $R$ and $L$, respectively. It is easy to prove that $R^* = L$ (the adjoint of $R$ is $L$). We have $W_m = R^m$. Now, for any vector $x\in\ell^2$ we have $(L^mx)_n = x_{m+n}$. Hence, for $x,y\in\ell^2$,
$$
|\langle R^mx,y\rangle|^2 = |\langle x,L^my\rangle|^2\,\le\,\|x\|_2^2\|L^my\|_2^2 = \|x\|_2^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty|y_{m+n}|^2 = \|x\|_2^2\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty|y_{n}|^2,
$$
which tends to zero.